# Why the assigned wires are x

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, circuit

I am implementing a MIPS Instruction decoder, but in the wave, I see all the assign logic variables like jump, immediate_i,regWrite etc as xxx, although I have initialized them as follows.  Even if I assume that, for eg., in jump, J is X, shoudn't it still go to 0 and not x?

```
 assign immediate_i = (opcode == (ADDI || ANDI || SLTI || XORI || LW || SW )) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
        assign memRead    =  LW ? 1'b1:1'b0;
        assign memtoReg   =  LW ? 1'b1:1'b0 ;
        assign memWrite   =  SW ? 1'b1:1'b0;
        assign jump       =  J ? 1'b1:1'b0;
        assign jumpReg    =  JR ? 1'b1:1'b0;
        assign bgtz       =  BGTZ ? 1'b1:1'b0;
```

---

```
module Instr_decode (
    input  logic signed [31:0]  instr,
    output logic                regDest, 
    output logic                jump,
    output logic                branch,
    output logic            bgtz,
    output logic                memtoReg,
    output logic                memRead,
    output logic                memWrite,
    output logic                regWrite,
    output logic        [8:0]   ALU_control,
    output logic signed [31:0]  imm_data_extended,
    output logic            target,
    output logic            immediate_i,
    output logic        [4:0]   shamt,
    output logic            jumpReg
);

    logic [5:0] opcode;
    logic [4:0] rs;
    logic [4:0] rt;
    logic [4:0] rd;
    logic [5:0] func;
    logic signed [15:0] immediate_data;
    logic signExtend_i;
    logic [4:0] wr_reg_addr; //for RF

    logic ADD;
    logic ADDI;
    logic AND;
    logic ANDI;
    logic BEQ;
    logic BGTZ;
    logic BNE;
    logic J ;
    logic JR ;
    logic LW ;
    logic NOR;
    logic OR ;
    logic ORI;
    logic SLT;
    logic SLTI;
    logic SRA;
    logic SUB;
    logic SW ;
    logic XOR;
    logic XORI;

    //Extracting the fields of Instruction bits
    assign opcode = instr[31:26];
    assign shamt = instr[10:6];
    assign func = instr[5:0];
    assign target = instr[25:0];
    assign immediate_data = immediate_i ? instr[15:0] : 16'dz;
    assign rs = instr[25:21];
    assign rt = instr[20:16];
    assign rd = instr[15:11];

    //assigning the decoder outputs
    assign immediate_i = (opcode == (ADDI || ANDI || SLTI || XORI || LW || SW )) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
    assign memRead    =  LW ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign memtoReg   =  LW ? 1'b1:1'b0 ;
    assign memWrite   =  SW ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign jump       =  J ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign jumpReg    =  JR ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign bgtz       =  BGTZ ? 1'b1:1'b0;
        assign regWrite   =  (ADD   | ADDI  | AND    | ANDI  | SUB   | OR     | XOR   | NOR  | SLT   | SLTI | LW   | SRA  | ORI   | XORI) ? 1'b1:1'b0 ;
    assign branch     =  (BEQ   | BNE) ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign regDest    =  (ADDI  | ANDI  | LW     | SW    | SLTI  | XORI) ? 1'b1:1'b0;

    //ALU Control logic output
    assign ALU_control[0] = (ADD | ADDI | LW | SW) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
    assign ALU_control[1] = (AND | ANDI) ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign ALU_control[2] = NOR ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign ALU_control[3] = OR ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign ALU_control[4] = (SLT | SLTI) ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign ALU_control[5] = SRA ? 1'b1:1'b0;
    assign ALU_control[6] = (SUB | BEQ) ? 1'b1:1'b0 ;
    assign ALU_control[7] = BNE ? 1'b1:1'b0 ;
    assign ALU_control[8] = (XOR | XORI) ? 1'b1:1'b0;


    //sign extension
    always_comb
    begin
         unique case({signExtend_i, immediate_data[15]})

        2'b0?  :    imm_data_extended = {{16{1'b0}}, immediate_data};
        2'b10  :    imm_data_extended = {{16{1'b0}}, immediate_data};
        2'b11  :    imm_data_extended = {{16{immediate_data[15]}}, immediate_data};
         endcase
    end

    //Input going to Register file
    always_comb
    begin
         case(regDest)
        1'b0:   wr_reg_addr = rt;
        1'b1:   wr_reg_addr = rd;
         endcase
    end

    //Control logic
    always_comb
    begin

         casez({opcode, func})

        {6'h00, 6'h20}      :   ADD = 1;
        {6'h08,  6'b??????}     :   ADDI = 1;
        {6'h00, 6'h24}      :   AND = 1;
        {6'h0C,  6'b??????} :   ANDI = 1;
        {6'h04,  6'b??????}     :   BEQ = 1;
        {6'h07,  6'b??????}     :       BGTZ = 1;
        {6'h05,  6'b??????}     :       BNE = 1;
        {6'h02,  6'b??????}     :   J = 1;
        {6'h00,  6'h8}      :   JR = 1;
        {6'h23,  6'b??????}     :   LW = 1;
        {6'h00, 6'h27}      :   NOR = 1;
        {6'h00, 6'h25}      :   OR = 1;
        {6'h00, 6'h2A}      :   SLT = 1;
        {6'h0A,  6'b??????}     :   SLTI = 1;
        {6'h00, 6'h03}      :   SRA = 1;
        {6'h00, 6'h22}      :   SUB = 1;
        {6'h2B,  6'b??????} :   SW = 1;
        {6'h00, 6'h26}      :   XOR = 1;
        {6'h0E,  6'b??????}     :       XORI = 1;
         endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I don't know why you need things like `assign memRead    =  LW ? 1'b1:1'b0;` What is wrong with `assign memRead    =  LW;`

Comment: nguthrie I did memRead = LW, but the issue of x initialization happened in that case. I can explain like this, when LW was 1, memRead was  = 1, but when LW was not 1 , memRead was getting x, which it should not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jump` is x because `J` is x.  A `logic` signal initializes to x at time 0.  My guess is that your `casez` never activates the `J = 1` line, so J remains x.

```
module tb;

logic J;
assign jump = J ? 1'b1:1'b0;
initial begin
    #5;
    $display($time, " J=%b jump=%b", J, jump);
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
               5 J=x jump=x
```